Error in OpenCV and Python for connect a camera with GigE
I'm using a DALSA linea C4096-7. I'm trying to connect to the camera via opencv but without success. I'm using the brand's SDK, sapera LT v8.31.
The error I get is as follows.
 [ WARN:0@170.390] global cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:453 _opencv_ffmpeg_interrupt_callback Stream timeout triggered after 30076.866000 ms

has anyone ever encountered this kind of problem?
It just sends me this message and doesn't give any kind of error.
The code:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import sys

os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "rtsp_transport;udp"

os.environ["OPENCV_LOG_LEVEL"] = "VERBOSE"
os.environ["OPENCV_VIDEOIO_DEBUG"] = "1"
os.environ["OPENCV_VIDEOCAPTURE_DEBUG"] = "1"

def connect_to_camera(ip_address, max_retries=5, retry_delay=5):

url = f"rtsp://{ip_address}/stream"
    for attempt in range(max_retries):
        print(f"Attempting to connect to camera (Attempt {attempt + 1}/{max_retries})...")
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_OPEN_TIMEOUT_MSEC, 5000)
        
        if cap.isOpened():
            print("Successfully connected to camera.")
            return cap
        else:
            print(f"Failed to connect. Retrying in {retry_delay} seconds...")
            time.sleep(retry_delay)
    
    print("Failed to connect to camera after multiple attempts.")
    return None

def process_frame(frame):
    return frame

def main():
    camera_ip = "169.254.1.1"  # Replace with your camera's actual IP
    cap = connect_to_camera(camera_ip)
    if cap is None:
        sys.exit(1)
    
    try:
        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                print("Failed to receive frame. Attempting to reconnect...")
                cap.release()
                cap = connect_to_camera(camera_ip)
                if cap is None:
                    break
                continue
            processed_frame = process_frame(frame)
            cv2.imshow('Frame', processed_frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
    
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Interrupted by user. Shutting down...")
    
    finally:
       
        if cap is not None:
            cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print("Camera released and windows closed.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Show your code!  And where does the error occur -- what line number?

There's a chance the URL is just wrong. Use another application to validate the stream URL like VLC.

To be frank, this is not the sort of camera I'd even remotely consider using OpenCV's VideoIO with, nor FFMPEG. There are a few industrial camera backends available, but you have to build OpenCV yourself, and even then they're quite limited.

I only intend to use live video for an app and have a routine  to capture images.

"DALSA linea C4096-7" -- is that really the model number? Linea range seem to be line cameras and there's no C4096. There is a Genie C4096 tho.

yes is the model name

I spoke to DALSA support and they say that the information on the site is wrong about compatibility with python... it doesn't make sense, I'll have to switch to C++ and then integrate it with python

sorry but lolwhat? what exactly did they say? there's no reason for the language to be a factor. they probably just didn't want to deal with the support request.

Basically their library is only in C++ C# or via their API, but the information on the site is different. They say it works with python, but that information is actually wrong...
